# Why does my stored procedure's LIKE clause return different data than regular query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOperatorNamesByComputer]
     (@computer nvarchar,
      @startdate datetime,
      @enddate datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MachineID) AS ID, 
        MachineID, User, [Datetime]
    FROM 
        MyTable
    WHERE 
        MachineID LIKE @computer + '%' 
        AND ([Datetime] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
        AND Description = 'Interesting Data'
END
```

I have this data in `MyTable` :

```
MachineID       User        Datetime              Description
------------------------------------------------------------------
F8;rweoi32234   person1     2017-10-31 00:01:01   Interesting Data
Test;fjdkkk11   person2     2017-10-20 00:02:00   Interesting Data
```

When I execute the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[GetOperatorNamesByComputer]
      @computer = N'F7', 
      @startdate = N'2017/10/01', @enddate = N'2017/10/31'
GO
```

it returns the row starting with F8, which seems to defy my search parameter. In fact, typing anything starting with the letter F in the `@computer` param will return all rows starting with F, despite what characters are also in the param.

But when I execute the regular query:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MachineID) AS ID, 
    MachineID, User, [Datetime]
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE
    MachineID LIKE 'F7%' 
    AND ([Datetime] BETWEEN '2017/10/01' AND '2017/10/31')
    AND Description = 'Interesting Data'
```

It returns no rows, as expected, and when changing the MachineID part to 'F8%', it will return one row.

Is this expected behavior of a LIKE clause in a stored procedure, or is it something wrong I've done when translating the query into a stored procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to declare a length for the parameter. `@computer nvarchar` Is the same as `@computer nvarchar(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nvarchar` parameter `@computer` in stored procedure declaration needs length. Like `nvarchar(20)`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!